# Failing to parse date in yyyyMMdd Hmm format using DateTime.TryParseExact()

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I am getting my date time in a format like "20170317 630"
which means 17 March 2017 6:30 am

Here is the code block I am trying, but it is failing.

```
var str = "20170317 0630";
var formatedTime = "yyyyMMdd Hmm";
DateTime etaDate;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(str,formatedTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out etaDate))  //formatedTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None
{
    Console.WriteLine("Date conversion failed " +  etaDate);
}

Console.WriteLine("Date conversion passed "+etaDate);
```

**Passing for: 20170317 0630**

**Failing for: 20170317 630**

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//split str in to strDate and strTime by using space
    var strDate = "20170317"; //Date part
    var strTime ="630";       //Time part
    if(strTime.Length ==3)   //check lenght of time part
    {
         strTime = "0" + strTime;  //Add extra zero
    }
    var formatedTime = "yyyyMMdd HHmm";
    DateTime etaDate;
    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate + strTime,formatedTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out etaDate))  //formatedTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Date conversion failed " +  etaDate);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Date conversion passed "+etaDate);
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely surprised it's failing to parse that - I suspect it's greedily parsing the "63" and deeming that to be an invalid hour number.

We have [exactly the same problem in Noda Time](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/issues/529) - and I don't intend to fix it. Making this work would be a *huge* amount of effort, and quite possibly reduce the performance for more sensible formats.

I would strongly suggest moving to a more sensible format, e.g. one of

- `H:mm` to remove the pseudo-ambiguity
- `HHmm` to make it all clearer
- `HH:mm` even better, IMO - preferrably with hyphens for date parts, so `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`

You can convert from one format to another by simply detecting the length of the string, as every other part of it is a fixed length. For example, to just move to using `HHmm` you can do:

```
if (str.Length == "yyyyMMdd Hmm".Length)
{
    str = str.Insert("yyyyMMdd ".Length, "0");
}
```

Then parse with `yyyyMMdd HHmm` format. If the length isn't right for *either* valid width, then it will fail to parse later anyway.

Comment: Should have know you would be faster haha. Good advice

Comment: Yes, I removed my comment as soon as you provided an example implementation. As long as everything before the date unconditionally is of a fixed length, that'll work. :)